# pipe mail to PHP script : cant find the pip.php file

Tags: php, pipe, cpanel

hi i'm trying to pipe incoming emails to php script 
i did step by step from my manual but when i send an email i get this error from my delivery system :

> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es)
>   failed:
>
> pipe to |/home2/mimjobco/public_html/pipe.php

i chosse pipe.php address from cpanel so it cant be wrong 
here is the picture !
[image]

here is my pipe.php code :

```
#!/usr/bin/php –q
<?php
require_once('class/support.php');
require_once('class/db.php');

   $title  = 'email_request';   
   $text   = 'email_req_text';  
   $sup_id = 1 ;    
   $sup = new support;
   $sup->title = $title;
   $sup->part_id = $sup_id ;
   $sup->text  = $text;
   $sup->email = 'email';
   $sup->type = 1;
   $sup->set_ticket();
   mail('xxxx@gmail.com','new message recived','new message recived ');
```

i also set it's permission to 755

am i missing something ?
is there another thing that i should have done? someone had mention something about crone job ?!

Comment: What's the result of `ls class/support.php` ? Are you sure that you executed your php file from the right directory ?

Comment: when i execute the page with url it works fine , i duno about directory though i've simply select the path that cpanel offered as u can see in the picture

Answer (score 1):

The error message says "/home2/mimjobco/pipe.php", but the screenshot shows the file is in your "public_html" directory (presumably, "/home2/mimjobco/public_html/pipe.php").

Note that "pipe.php" should only be in "public_html" if you want it to be accessible on the website. Otherwise, it should go elsewhere in your home directory hierarchy (e.g. ~/bin/).

Comment: even better outside the home dir altogether

Comment: @Dagon: I doubt Max has write permission outside of ~. Moreover, there's no advantage to placing the script outside of ~.

Comment: why? even on my cheap hosts i can create a dir below home for storage of backups. and the advantage is its not accessible over the web (as it doesn't need to be).

Comment: @Dagon: placing the script in a subdir of ~ (such as ~/bin, as shown as an example in my answer) doesn't place it outside the home directory hiercharchy; it's squarely in the hierarchy. Placing it outside ~ would mean the full path to the file wouldn't start with "/home2/mimjobco/".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using bluehost, here is someone else who was able to fix the problem: http://www.bluehostforum.com/showthread.php?5786-Reading-email-with-php&p=26554#post26554

> Setting up filter in cPanel, problem that delivery error coming back. Many solutions not available on a shared server.
>
> Finally, this seems to work to avoid the error in delivery emails coming back - note the -q:
>
> |/usr/bin/php -q /home/myacct/public_html/mydir/myfile.php
>
> Solution came from http://forums.exocrew.com/index.php?showtopic=1838. (DEAD LINK)
>
> The code for parsing emails being piped to the php file is at:
>
> http://evolt.org/node/27914/
>
> This gives you the message parsed as variables for subject, from, body etc.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The script already has a shebang line and calls `php` with the `-q` option.

Comment: I know it does but this is what other people had to do to get it working with BlueHost, it's not "How it is supposed to work" it is "What works"

Comment: The question is not "what works?" Max is asking why his particular set-up is failing with the given error. This answer doesn't address what's causing the error message for Max and won't solve Max's issue, though it may help others with a different set-up and problem but the same error message (hence, no down-vote).